Plaid /institutions/get/ doesn't seem to respect country_codes
I am new to Plaid, and just trying to get the basics working, but I've immediately hit an issue.
I can't (don't want to) use the "out of the box" link SDK (see this github issue), so I'm trying to implement my own UX that does broadly the same thing.
The documentation for the "institutions" endpoint, has the following sample API request:
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/institutions/get \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "client_id": "${PLAID_CLIENT_ID}",
  "secret": "${PLAID_SECRET}",
  "count": Number,
  "offset": Number,
  "country_codes": Array
}'

If I execute this, either via curl or via a tool like Postman, I do indeed get results, but not what I expect. Here is my curl:
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/institutions/get \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "client_id": "REDACTED",
  "secret": "REDACTED",
  "offset": 0,
  "count": 10,
  "country_codes": ["US"]
}'

This returns successfully, but returns the following:
{
    "institutions": [
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122874",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Bourgogne Franche Comté",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122875",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Auvergne et Rhône-Alpes",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122876",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Rives de Paris",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122877",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Val de France",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122878",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - du Nord",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122879",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Sud",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122880",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Aquitaine Centre Atlantique",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122881",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Alsace Lorraine Champagne",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122882",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Occitane",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        },
        {
            "country_codes": [
                "FR"
            ],
            "credentials": [],
            "has_mfa": true,
            "input_spec": "unknown",
            "institution_id": "ins_122883",
            "mfa": [
                "code",
                "list",
                "questions",
                "selections"
            ],
            "mfa_code_type": "numeric",
            "name": "Banque Populaire - Grand Ouest",
            "oauth": true,
            "products": [
                "assets",
                "auth",
                "balance",
                "transactions",
                "signal",
                "identity_match",
                "income_verification",
                "identity",
                "payment_initiation",
                "processor_payments",
                "transfer"
            ],
            "routing_numbers": []
        }
    ],
    "request_id": "AVhWWp9iNUGsvRb",
    "total": 11837
}

As you can see, these are all French banks. It seems like the plaid API is not respecting the country_codes property of the request body.
Has anyone else got this to work? Is there some trick I need to know here?

OK, so after inspecting the request/response pairs of Plaid's Node.js client library, it seems you need to also supply a Plaid-Version header:
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/institutions/get \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Plaid-Version: 2020-09-14' \
-d '{
  "client_id": "REDACTED",
  "secret": "REDACTED",
  "offset": 0,
  "count": 10,
  "country_codes": ["US"]
}'

This is documented in their API Versioning docs, but not actually used in the samples for their main API docs

To add on to the given answer -- this issue occurs if using a Plaid API version prior to 2020-09-14, since the syntax for sending the country_codes for the /institutions/get endpoint changed in that version. So if your default API version is earlier than 2020-09-14, sending 2020-09-14 in the request as a version header will fix the issue.
If you created your Plaid team on or after 2020-09-14, you don't need to send a version header, since your team will be using the latest API version by default. You can also configure the settings for which API version to use by default in the Plaid Dashboard rather than sending a version header.

Thanks for this info. I think I did create the account some time ago. Sadly I am not able to get Plaid to work.. it just gives me errors so I've abandoned it and chosen an alternate
